# implementing a MLP model in keras for timeseries prediction but the model doesn't train well

Tags: neural-network, keras, deep-learning

I'm trying to come up with a MLP model for timeseries prediction following [this blog post](https://machinelearningmastery.com/time-series-prediction-with-deep-learning-in-python-with-keras/). I have 138 timeseries with a lookback_window=28 (splitted as 50127 timeseries for traing and 24255 timeseries for validation). I need to predict the next value (timesteps=28, n_features=1). I started from a 3 layer network but it didn't train well. I tried to make the network deeper by adding more layers/more hunits, but it doesn't improve. In the picture, you can see the result of prediction of the following model Here is my model code:

```
    inp = Input(batch_shape=(batch_size, lookback_window))
    first_layer = Dense(1000, input_dim=28, activation='relu')(inp)
    snd_layer = Dense(500)(first_layer)
    thirs_layer = Dense(250)(snd_layer)
    tmp = Dense(100)(thirs_layer)
    tmp2 = Dense(50)(tmp)
    tmp3 = Dense(25)(tmp2)
    out = Dense(1)(tmp3)
    model = Model(inp, out)
    model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam')
    history = model.fit(train_data, train_y,
                        epochs=1000,
                        batch_size=539,
                        validation_data=(validation_data, validation_y),
                        verbose=1,
                        shuffle=False)
```

What am I missing? How can I improve it?

[image]

Comment: Are you scaling or normalizing your data in some way?

Comment: The predictions look plausible to me. What are you expecting here?

Comment: @sdcbr yes, I used minMaxScale to scale data between -1 and 1. The plot shows the values after scaling them back

Comment: @ThomasPinetz The predicted values (orange curve) are very different from the expected values :/ After training for 1000 epochs I was expecting to see a better results, and the orange curve follow the blue line more precisely.  I trained a smaller model similar to this for only 10 timeseries and I could get a better prediction but when I increase the size of data it doesn't work anymore

Comment: @Birish Could you post the loss curve during training? Have you tried changing the learning rate?

Comment: My intuition here is that MLP are not good at capturing long range dependencies (you have a window of 28 time steps right?) thus it is not taking advantages of all those data. Have you tried to reduce the lookback_window to 3/4? In case you want to keep the window this big I suggest you to use an LSTM instead of MLP.

Comment: @TommasoPasini Good point thanks! Actually, I'm trying to compare an MLP model with a LSTM model.

Comment: I see, many effort are currently put in proving that feed forward network are comparable to LSTM in terms of accuracy but are much faster (e.g. http://bair.berkeley.edu/blog/2018/08/06/recurrent/)

Comment: @TommasoPasini Thanks for the link :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get better results by the following changes:

- Using `RMSprop` instead of Adam with `lr=0.001`, and as @TommasoPasini mentioned added them to all Dense layers (expect the last one). It improves the results a lot!
- epochs= 3000 instead of 1000.

But now I think it is overfitting. Here are the plots of the results and the validation and train loss:

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

The main thing I noticed is that you are not using non-linearities in your layers. I would use relus for the hidden layers and linear layer for the final layer in case you want values larger than 1 / -1 to be possible. If you do not want them to be possible use tanh. By increasing the data you make the problem harder and therefore your mostly linear model is underfitting severely.

Comment: Just tried again with adding 'relu' to all dense layers (except the last one). It improves the prediction results a little bit but still quite off :(